# Showing phpMyAdmin databases in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I have set up a new database with phpMyAdmin, but when I log in to MySQL through terminal (Mac OS X 10.9.5) it doesnt show up the new database i created. it only shows 'information_schema' and 'test'.

Is there a certain directory I should go to in terminal before starting mySQL?

Comment: with which user did you create the database , and with which user do you try to access it? And to which user did you grant permission on the newly created db?

Answer (score 0):

You might be using two different schemas for MySQL server and in phpMyAdmin.

As a check, you can try creating a table from terminal, and see if it gets reflected in phpMyAdmin, `create table A (a varchar(), b varchar() )`. If the new table doesnot appear from the browser (phpMyAdmin) probably you are logging in from two different schemas.

Also FYI: It doesnot matter from which directory do you login to MySQL.

Hope it helps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

When I log into mySQL using "mysql -u root -p" i can access all the databases.

Comment: So you need to change the permissions on the databases so you can access them with other users. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html